# Why my server isn't accessible from outside?

Tags: port-forwarding, dmz

I'm trying to make a Minecraft server. It works fine in LAN but my friends cannot access it outside of my LAN. I tried port forwarding (TCP/UDP 25565) but it didn't work. I turned off the windows firewall for everything and it didn't work. I also tried DMZ and it didn't work. Even when I turned off my router's firewall it didn't work.

How can I fix this? It's 6 months that I'm trying to fix my problem.

I have a dynamic IP. I'm not using a domain name. My connection is DSL and my ISP Cosmote(Greece).

I give my friends my public IPV4. I tried putting and the port number next to the IP(x.x.x.x:25565)

What's the problem?

Comment: Does _your router_ (and not a random website) say that you have a public IPv4 address? And does that address reported by the router exactly match the one shown by websites?

Comment: @user1686 My router doesn't say anything about that. It's the router from my ISP. I don't know.

Comment: Hmm, even the very limited ones usually have _some_ sort of "status" or "system info" page where the "WAN address" or "PPPoE address" is shown, if nothing else. Try to search for it again.

Comment: @user1686 I couldn't find the current IPV4. I searched for that and no results.

Comment: What IP addresses are returned by [What Is My IP Address - See Your Public Address - IPv4 & IPv6](https://whatismyipaddress.com/)?

Comment: Without an ISP static IP, you need to have a [DDNS](https://www.lifewire.com/definition-of-dynamic-dns-816294) address. Once done, set up [port redirects](https://portforward.com/minecraft/) on the router _(do not use UPnP or a DMZ - neither are secure)_ and configure firewall rules for the traffic on the machine running the Minecraft server _(do not disable Windows Firewall without a third-party firewall installed - you need an OS firewall for data security)_